# Rating system in web application

Tags: java, jpa, architecture, rating-system

I'm trying to create a rating system (as a reputation system in reddit and Stackoverflow) in my web application.

What is the right way to store that rating?

```
@Entity
Class User {
   Long id
   ...
   @OneToOne
   CustomRating rating
}

@Entity
Class CustomRating {

  @ManyToOne
  Set<User> upvotes;

  @ManyToOne
  Set<User> downvotes;
}
```

This is the best I can do. Is it possible to make it better?

Thank you!

P.s. every vote should be unique. One person cannot vote twice

Comment: Are you only concerned about cumulative up and down votes?

Comment: @HariHaravelan yes

Comment: CustomRating can have just int or long of `upVoteCounts` and `downVoteCounts` no?

Comment: @HariHaravelan no. One person can't vote twice, that's why I need to keep tracking it

Answer (score 0):

Since your `User` is going to have upvotes and downvotes by other users i suggest to have it all in `User` entity itself, like below

```
@Entity
class User {
    Long id;
    set<User> upVotedUsers;
    set<User> downVotedUsers;
}
```